# How to install NuGet from command line on linux

Tags: linux, nuget

I need to install NuGet on Linux based machine.When am using the following command in Windows machine it works fine.

**nuget install packages.config**

But I am unable to do this with linux machine, how to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://headsigned.com/article/running-nuget-command-line-on-linux)

Answer (score 97):

Once you've followed the (somewhat annoying) install steps to get .Net core installed and the apt repo setup from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core, you can just do this:

```
sudo apt install nuget
```

and you'll have a working nuget on your local machine:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l

$ nuget
NuGet Version: 2.8.7.0
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options] 
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.
```

Notice that as of the time of writing do *not* run `nuget update -self`, as although it will successfully install a more recent version of nuget, that version won't actually run.

If you *do* break it though, you can always just blow it away and reinstall:

```
sudo apt remove nuget
sudo apt install nuget
```

Comment: I tried this answer on openSuse 15.0 with no luck. Gave me this output 
```Retrieving repository 'openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update' metadata ...............[done]
Building repository 'openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update' cache ....................[done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'nuget' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'nuget' found.
Resolving package dependencies...
```

Comment: @mdzeko On openSuse you may need to use "mono-nuget" instead of nuget as the package name; I don't know why they chose to package it under that, but you can see the package here --> https://software.opensuse.org/ymp/openSUSE:Leap:15.1/standard/mono-nuget.ymp?base=openSUSE%3ALeap%3A15.1&query=mono-nuget

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that already and tried as well, but to no avail. I have a container that runs Debian so your original answer was helpful after all. Thanks again.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Newer versions requide dotnet-sdk or mono-complete

Comment: I can confirm, that in 2023, debian bookworm still installs nuget 2.8.7 and `nuget update -self` still does not work :(

Answer (score 29):

Install mono, then download nuget:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
wget https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
```

After then run it using `mono nuget.exe`.

Comment: You might want to copy it to `/usr/lib/nuget/NuGet.exe` also, so that the `nuget` command will work. That one looks like this on Ubuntu 16.4:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/cli /usr/lib/nuget/NuGet.exe "$@"
```

Comment: nuget has some weird finicky compatibility issues that are affected by the version of mono, so make sure you're actually pulling the latest version. I don't believe apt will always get the latest one: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu

Comment: on Ubuntu 16.04, the latest (https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe) version of nuget use a newer framework than the system mono supports.

Comment: For 16.04 4.5.1 is the latest that works. https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86- commandline/v4.5.1/nuget.exe (4.6.2 doesn't work)

Comment: Just adding this here for anyone getting System.Net.Http errors while trying to run nuget on linux / wsl, try installing mono-complete even if mono seems to be installed.

Answer (score 16):

nuget apt package doesn't really work on linux, and exe's are for windows.  If you want to run nuget the easiest thing is to use mono wrapper.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
//download nuget.exe
mono nuget.exe install
```

Comment: Went with this solution.  .NET for Linux doesn't have 32-bit support.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the [Microsoft instructions for installing Nuget on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#cli-tools):

1. Install [Mono 4.4.2 or later](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/).
2. Execute the following command at a shell prompt (Bash):

   ```
   # Download the latest stable `nuget.exe` to `/usr/local/bin` 
   sudo curl -o /usr/local/bin/nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
   ```
3. Create an alias by adding the following script to the appropriate file for your OS (typically `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bash_profile`)(Bash):

   ```
   # Create as alias for nuget
   alias nuget="mono /usr/local/bin/nuget.exe"
   ```
4. Reload the shell. Test the installation by entering `nuget` with no parameters. NuGet CLI help should display.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use `nuget` with WSL2, the steps are as follows.

1. Download *nuget.exe* through `wget https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe`
2. Create a bash file called `nuget`:

```sh
> nuget
# Or
vi nuget
```

3. Edit the file with the content below (`vim nuget`, then `i`):

```sh
# Edit the file with - make sure to add the correct path to nuget.exe file
'nuget.exe' $@ &
```

4. Make it executable.

```sh
# Make it executable
chmod +x nuget
```

5. Add to the $PATH environment variable

```sh
# Edit .bashrc
vi .bashrc
```

6. Insert `export PATH=/path/to/nuget-folder:$PATH` in the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way if you just need the package might be to use `curl` or `wget` and `unzip`. The script may look like:

```bash
curl -L -o package.zip https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/<target_package>

unzip package.zip -d <target_folder>
```

*Pay attention to the `-L` curl flag that tells curl to follow any redirects. It's common that nuget would redirect you to a CDN.*

Now, you have the latest nuget package in your desired folder. Optionally, you can target a specific version by appending the url with `/<version>`.

---

Examples:

```bash
curl -L -o package.zip https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Language
...

unzip package.zip -d test
Archive:  package.zip
  inflating: test/_rels/.rels
  inflating: test/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Language.nuspec
  inflating: test/lib/net472/Kusto.Language.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net472/Kusto.Language.xml
  inflating: test/lib/net5.0/Kusto.Language.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net5.0/Kusto.Language.xml
  inflating: test/lib/netcoreapp2.1/Kusto.Language.dll
  inflating: test/lib/netcoreapp2.1/Kusto.Language.xml
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard2.0/Kusto.Language.dll
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard2.0/Kusto.Language.xml
  inflating: test/EULA-agreement.txt
  inflating: test/MSFT.png
  inflating: test/[Content_Types].xml
  inflating: test/package/services/metadata/core-properties/0878db782482414487821399a0d09728.psmdcp
 extracting: test/.signature.p7s

cat test/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Language.nuspec | grep "<version>"
    <version>11.1.0</version>
```

```bash
curl -L -o package.zip https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.2
...

unzip package.zip -d test
Archive:  package.zip
  inflating: test/LICENSE.md
  inflating: test/Newtonsoft.Json.nuspec
  inflating: test/packageIcon.png
  inflating: test/README.md
  inflating: test/[Content_Types].xml
  inflating: test/_rels/.rels
  inflating: test/lib/net20/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net20/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/net35/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net35/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/net6.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/net6.0/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard1.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard1.0/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard1.3/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard1.3/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  inflating: test/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
  inflating: test/package/services/metadata/core-properties/66867671be6046c2a70df93bfa9634b8.psmdcp
 extracting: test/.signature.p7s

cat test/Newtonsoft.Json.nuspec | grep "<version>"
    <version>12.0.2</version>
```