# MathNet.numerics fsharp with visual code

Tags: .net, f#-interactive, mathnet-numerics

I would like to use MathNet.Numerics in my fsharp script file (I am very newbie). My OS is ubuntu and I am using visual code.

Would you know the best way to load this package in my script file?

I thank you in advance.
Robi

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read through tips 5 and 6 in this excellent primer on fsi: http://brandewinder.com/2016/02/06/10-fsharp-scripting-tips/

In a nutshell, you load a dll using the `#r` directive, for example:

```
#r @"../packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.5/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
```

Now, to get MathNet to your packages folder, you can use nuget, or for more complex projects it is recommended to use paket.

[How to install NuGet from command line on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118548/how-to-install-nuget-from-command-line-on-linux).

https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/installation.html