# NuGet on the Docker

Tags: docker, nuget

Is there a way get NuGet on a linux based Docker image?

I tried this:

```
ARG PAT

FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY src/IdentityServer/ ./

# the annoying NuGet installation
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt-get install nuget
RUN nuget sources add -name yyyy-source https://xxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/yyyy/nuget/v3/index.json -username dummy -password ${PAT}
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServer.dll"]
```

I get this:

```
Step 5/13 : RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db337597f4fe
Step 6/13 : RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
 ---> Running in c361881586a3
Selecting previously unselected package packages-microsoft-prod.
(Reading database ... 12109 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack packages-microsoft-prod.deb ...
Unpacking packages-microsoft-prod (1.0-3) ...
Setting up packages-microsoft-prod (1.0-3) ...
Removing intermediate container c361881586a3
 ---> 6a56d436e5da
Step 7/13 : RUN apt-get install nuget
 ---> Running in c47705590796
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package nuget
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install nuget' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

but some people have success getting that NuGet package installed on Linux:
[How to install NuGet from command line on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118548/how-to-install-nuget-from-command-line-on-linux)

Comment: Had you tried updating repository cache in between via `apt-get update` (after installing packages-microsoft-prod.deb) ? Docker does not perform much magic itself internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the only reason you're trying to get nuget.exe is to add credentials. [This page in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=vsts) has links on how to authenticate to Azure Devops using the dotnet cli. Your use case falls into the "otherwise" sentence of the CI builds section, so you can [use an environment variable](https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/blob/master/README.md#environment-variables) to specify your PAT. Therefore, you don't actually need nuget.

Comment: yes that is the right solution.  Thank you!  It's not simple and I wish the authors of the plugin had a docker section, but... it can be figured out.

Comment: docker docs also suggest that the `ARG PAT` is available up to an including the `FROM ...` but not after the `FROM ...`.  If your use-case, the `ARG PAT` should be after the `FROM ...`.