# How to install the latest version of NuGet.exe CLI in Ubuntu 18.04 WSL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nuget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL 18.04 (Ubuntu) and I want to use NuGet.exe to install a Nuget Package to a folder (not .csproj) using the code below:

```
nuget install Test.Nuget.Version -OutputDirectory packages
```

In WSL, I use `sudo apt install nuget`. However that will only install an old nuget version 2.8.xxx in Ubuntu. =(

In order to run `nuget install` command, I must use the latest version of NuGet version (5.x.x) installed in Ubuntu.

Is it possible to install latest NuGet version in Ubuntu?
If yes, how can I do so?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/38118548

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can get nuget to update itself:

```
nuget.exe update -self
```

However recently, because I assume they have updated the min TLS version, one can get the following error:

```
The authentication or decryption has failed.
  Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException:
```

So your nuget version has to be new enough to upgrade itself.

So you have to get a new nuget.exe by alternative means:

```
curl https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe -o nuget.exe
```

**UPDATE**: a few years latter the latest nuget.exe doesn't work on 18.04, (likely not compatible with the system mono)

The last one to work is 5.2.1:

```
curl https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.2.1/nuget.exe -o nuget.exe
```

Note you will likely also have to `chmod +x nuget.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Now another solution might be to work around this some docs from the Mono project : https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian.
This is a good start for debian, and it actually also works for Ubuntu.

I ended up with this configuration in a WSL ubuntu 22.04 box :

```
# First, import a new key that is used by the mono repository
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

# Then, add the repo in apt configs :
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list

# Update apt database (will fetch distant repositories, and will complain that the mono repo is deprecated)
apt update
apt-cache policy nuget # Should return several versions, usually 2.8 and 6.6
apt-get install nuget # will install the nuget 6.6 with the appropriate mono libs for it to work
```

This procedure works (with some warnings along the way). It might not be the most reliable one, and certainly not part of the usual "easy to install" user experience that we would need for the nuget package manager, but anyways, it does the job.

Hope this will help other guys in the future !